# Regex validation on UTF8 / multi byte 'language' characters (inc chinese etc) but not special characters such as {/*

Tags: php, regex, validation, utf-8, non-latin

Using PHP / MySQL all encoded up as UTF, we have recently had to start capturing non-Latin characters, such as Chinese etc. We have PHP validation that checks the string length and alpha numeric such as:

```
if (!ereg("[[:alnum:]]{2,}",$_POST['company_name'])) {
    //error code here
}
```

This is not working on multi byte chars. I understand about the length being an issue (one char is not equal to one byte) but I was hoping if someone could provide a link / solution for  matching a string for UTF8 language characters only NO special characters such as `[*/` etc.

EDIT: I want to accept only a string that is xx long and only contains language characters alebit English / Chinese etc. and NOT any special characters `*{/` etc. Hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: What is the expected matching -- do you want to accept those non-Latin characters? Currently seems you're checking alphanumeric so those other chars won't be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a little vague, but you can enforce only letters (possibly combined with marks) and decimal numbers with

```
if (!preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}]{2,}$/u', $_POST['company_name'])) {
   //error here
}
```

Comment: Im a regex nube so pls be patient!  I can not get this to work I have tried with the three vars below but always throws error - pls help! Thanks

$var = "若您是参展商"; // same result
//$var = "test"; // same result
//$var = "test{}/'*/-";

    if (!preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nd}]{2,}$/u', $var)) {
      echo "Not just Unicode languaage chars - error";
    }

Comment: @user It works. See here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kGxOG2 Make sure your data is actually encoded in UTF-8 (for instance, the characters are not encoded with HTML entities).

Comment: Thanks for the patience - I do believe you that your code works but - I am running the exact same code on our server - using true utf8 chars and both are failing? ' $var fails $var2 fails ' - we have same php version as the codepad could there be any other server vars / settings that would make your regex fail? Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: @user Check if the output of [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VroOuL) is the same.

Comment: Have just run the exact same code on our server and still both vars fail.  Without wanting to pester you too much any more suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: @user Is the output of the first var_dump the same (the long string)?

Answer (score 0):

The **mbstring** extension of PHP has an [mb_ereg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php) function, this would probably be a good starting point, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match with `\p{L}|\p{N}` but you need to add the `u` option to your regex.

**Sources :**
[www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)